# FB Messenger bot link doesn't redirects user to Messenger

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm sharing a bot link in FB Groups but when users using low/mid-end Android click the link nothing happens and the user is lost. Sometimes the OS even asks the user if they want to open it in Messenger App but then nothing happens.

I'm trying a m.me link and a bitly. In Whatsapp I'm seeing the same behaviour.

Is there any workaround to make it work?

Thanks.